# Should not import the named export in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, import

i have a config.json file where i stocked all my BaseUrls and API_KEYS but, when i'm trying to import these from other component i get this error : **Should not import the named export 'API_URL_Geo' (imported as 'config') from default-exporting module (only default export is available soon) **, i tried 2 methods of importing

```
import * as config from "../config.json";

config.API_URL_GEO
```

and

```
import {API_URL_Geo} from "../config.json";
```

but i still get same errors, any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the answer was pretty simple, just importing config directly here  it is :

```
import config from "../config.json";
```

and then access everything like this :

```
API_KEY_1 = config.API_KEY_1
```