# "React Hooks in Action" exercise error : filter not found in JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I am doing the exercises in John Larsen's book *React Hooks in Action*, chapter 2. When I clone his [repository](https://github.com/jrlarsen/react-hooks-in-action/tree/0202-hard-coded), the react app starts successfully. However, when I write it myself  (and check again that I did not overlook any piece of code), I get an error.

Here's my minimal code to reproduce the problem :

My project's structure is

```
public
  index.html
src
  components
    App.js
  index.js
  static.json
package.json
```

The content of `static.json` is copied from his [git repo](https://github.com/jrlarsen/react-hooks-in-action/blob/0202-hard-coded/src/static.json).

Here's the content of `App.js`

```
import {bookables} from "../static.json";

export default function App() {
  const bookablesInGroup = bookables.filter(b => b.group === "Room");

  return ( <p>Hello</p>  )
}
```

And I get the following error

```
ERROR in ./src/components/App.js 7:27-43
export 'bookables'.'filter' (imported as 'bookables') was not found in '../static.json' (possible exports: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

My first idea was to add an export in `static.json`, but it's clearly not the solution. It's driving me crazy. What did I overlook ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution by changing

```
import {bookables} from "../static.json";
```

to

```
import data from "../../static.json";
...
const { bookables } = data;
```

I found the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/73143324/471461 and [ES6 Destructuring and Module imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524696/es6-destructuring-and-module-imports).

It seems that I mixed between *named imports* and *destructuring* in the import statement, though I don't know why the exemples in the book work.

Answer (score 1):

bookables is a property inside the JSON data. `filter` is a function available for array objects.
In your previous case, you imported `bookables` from the static JSON, and it was referring to the JSON data. In that case you had to do filter on `bookables.bookables` (the first bookables refers to the imported data, and the second bookables refers to the array bookables inside the JSON data).

```
import data from "../../static.json";
...
const { bookables } = data;
```

worked because, in the import you are calling the JSON Data as `data`, and in the next line, you are extracting the property `bookables` from the JSON data. And, `bookables` is now an array and you are able to invoke filter on it.

In short, in the first case you were trying to invoke `filter` on the JSON object, and in the working scenario, you are invoking `filter` on the array element inside the JSON object.

Hope this helps